# Custom Authentication handler for mod_auth_form?

Tags: authentication, apache-2.4

Apache 2.3/2.4 has [mod_auth_form](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html) that allows to display a HTML form for users to login. Can I, instead of using a plain HTML form use an application server to provide the form (J2EE, node.js, PHP, Vert.x etc) and the authentication logic and just return the session cookie (how would that need to look like?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But you need to use input fields with name = httpd_username and httpd_password (and .htaccess rights as well)


/secret/path/.htaccess

```
AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation /login.html
AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation /secret/path/
AuthFormProvider file
AuthUserFile /before/www/root/.htpasswd
AuthType form
AuthName "My server!"
Session On
SessionCookieName session path=/secret/path/
SessionCryptoPassphrase SomEtH1n9
```

/logout/.htaccess

```
AuthName "My server!"
AuthFormLogoutLocation /logout/
Session On
SessionCookieName session path=/secret/path/
SessionCryptoPassphrase SomEtH1n9
```

p.s.: don't use "secret" word from Apache Docs as a passphrase ;)

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? the .htaccess file above points to a file system based html file - that's not the question. I'm looking for a transparent way - Apache gets the cookie and it is up to the app server how it was created (e.g. 2FA or a game played)